# Why would a string of methods need to be separated?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm implementing a reactive line chart in meteor.js based on [this example line chart](https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-cookbook/tree/master/d3/d3-example/client/line).  In the code that I lifted for that chart, I have the following block, which works fine.

```
var paths = svg.selectAll("path.line")
  .data([dataset]);

paths
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('d', line);

paths
  .attr('d', line);

paths
  .exit()
  .remove();
```

However, when I try writing something like the following, the axes still show, but the path does not render.  Why the heck could that be?

```
var paths = svg.selectAll("path.line")
      .data([dataset])
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr('d', line)
    .exit()
      .remove();
```

Comment: maybe in the second one, when you put attr('d', line).attr("d', line); the second 'd' overwrites the first. where as in the first way you did it, it added it. Try splitting them up and see if it works

Comment: edited that out.  That part is in the first one too though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling the functions on different objects. D3 returns update, enter, and exit selections from calls to `.data()` -- this is what you're storing in `paths` in the first code block. Then you get the enter, update, and exit selections and handle them.

In the second code block, you're calling `.enter()` you're handling the enter selection afterwards. That is, all the code after the `.enter()` is being applied to the enter selection and not to the other selections as well as before.

So the `.exit().remove()` is being called on the newly-appended `path` elements (which should give you an error) instead of the return value of `.data()` as in the first block of code.

Comment: So it's like a fork?  Also, what does the line `paths.attr('d', line)` act on?

Comment: No, each of the `.function` calls operates on the return value of the previous operation. That means the thing you're operating on may change throughout the chain, which is what's happening in your second code block. `paths.attr('d', line)` in your first code block operates on the update selection (there's no separate function to call to get to that).